# iOS ionic 3 - CORS error on iOS iphone device - Origin localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ios, rest, http, cors, ionic3

I cannot access REST API. CORS problem on ionic 3 iOS build

Below is a screenshot of the problem. I use Safari to check the console messages of the iOS ionic app
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL9aA.jpg

Here is how I made the api call

```
        var url = this.baseurl.baseurl();
        var data = "username=" + this.username + "&password=" + this.password + "&device_uuid=ionic";
        this.http.post(url + 'parent/parent_login_with_companyname', encodeURI(data), { headers: new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__angular_common_http__["c" /* HttpHeaders */]().set('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') })
            .subscribe(function (res) {
            loading_1.dismiss();
            window.localStorage.setItem('parent_info', JSON.stringify(res));
            _this.navCtrl.setRoot(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__tabs_tabs__["a" /* TabsPage */]);
        }, function (err) {
```

Comment: Can you show us the request and response headers (domain obfuscated if necessary), so we can see what values are passed for the `Origin` request header and for the various `Access-Control-*` response headers.

Comment: how do i show that ? from the network its just like this https://imgur.com/a/A1pyX

Comment: Can you do a curl, maybe? I don't use Safari, so I'm not sure how to see the request/response headers.

Comment: @Axil How did you solve this Please help me I am stuck in this since last many days

Comment: i cant quite remember, i'll get back abit later on this. if you do find the solution please post it up here.

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUTION**

After a very long search I found this holy grail! Hope this works for you as it did for me:
http://uncaughterror.com/programming/ionic3/preflight-response-issue-with-ionic3-app-on-ios-build-only-resolved/

Answer (score -2):

You can disable the same-origin policy on Safari , in order to disable it you only need to enable the developer menu, and select "**Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions**" from the develop menu.

This you can do when you are in development phase. You will not get this issue when you will move application to live server and can access it without disabling cross -origin restrictions.

Comment: this is not on the web but on ios platform device.

Comment: you will not get this error on device if your device and server is in same network. You are now testing it on browser so you are getting this error. So till you are developing and testing it on safari go ahead with disabling cross domain restrictions. If you are in same network then you will not face issue on realtime device.